# Excel VBA: string operation not working

Tags: string, vba, excel

I am trying to work with a string (copied into a cell from `.txt`) like below:

```
"                                    ========   =============   ========   =====================   ==================   =================================================================   ==================================================   =============   =================="
```

basically, it's a combo of equal signs and spaces, but I need to do a few things with it later. This is what I did:

```
targetstring3 = Range("A7").Value
Range("B8").Value = Mid(targetstring3, 57, 2)
```

And it returned

> "application/object-defined error"

I tried this below and it's still not working:

```
targetstring3 = Cstr(Range("A7").Value)
Range("B8").Value = Mid(targetstring3, 57, 2)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What line and function call EXACTLY throw the exception? First or second? See what code is highlighted when the error occurs.

Comment: try using a variable (let's say `temp`) to store the value of `Mid(targetstring3, 57, 2)` before assigning it to `B8`. I feel as though I had run into similar issues doing some of my earlier macros and that that helped. Not to say it should be a permanent fix, but if it gets your code running whilst waiting for a better answer, that's helpful at least.

Comment: The error itself didn't highlight any line (normally the error would be a "400" error but I added an error handling code which enabled it to show me "application...object-defined error..."). But I deleted the Range("B8").Value = Mid(targetstring3, 57, 2) line and it worked perfectly, with the same mid expression on other strings intact, which is why I thought that line was the error

Comment: Try what @USFBS said (`foo = Mid(...)`) and see if it throws

Comment: Try typing two equals signs into a cell without prefacing them with a single quote.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that you will get an error. Remember that Excel formulas start with an `=` sign. And hence you get an error.

Change your code to

```
Range("B8").Value = "'" & Mid(targetstring3, 57, 2)
```

or

```
Range("B8").Value = Chr(34) & Mid(targetstring3, 57, 2) & Chr(34)
```

**Edit**

Followup from comments

I tried this

```
Sub Sample()
    targetstring3 = Range("A1").Value
    Range("B8").Value = Chr(34) & Mid(targetstring3, 57, 2) & Chr(34)
    Range("B9").Value = "'" & Mid(targetstring3, 57, 2)
End Sub
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I changed it to
    john = "'" & Mid(targetstring3, 57, 2)
and it gave the same error - what's happening?

Comment: Can you please try your code with some value different than all equal signs?

Comment: Thanks! Just found a way around it, I replaced = with "+" and could achieve same thing for all intent and purposes (just need to change it back later in the very end). Sorry for all the fuss!